# Can I vent my bathroom with Air Return Grilles?

Tags: hvac, bathroom, air-conditioning, vent, exhaust-fan

My apartment’s small full bathroom is about 50 sq ft, and there was an old Non-Vented Air Recirculating Fan in the ceiling. It died but there was still moisture/mold/mildew issues when it worked.

I need something better but The Non-Venting Fans always seem like such a waste, and cutting a hole in the side of the building isn’t an option at the moment. I know that code says I can only exhaust my bathroom to the  outside.

However, can I cut a hole through the wall, make a mini-duct channel, and put a couple return grilles on either side?

I’d seal the interior of the holes so the air wouldn’t go into the walls and only back and forth. I’ve seen this passive air exchange setup done for bedrooms and closets, but I wanted to know if it could be done from the bathroom to the kitchen, which is 10’ away from the HVAC Air Handler/Return.

Also, I live in FL, as for Local Code Guidelines if that matters. I’ve read a lot but haven’t found a good answer so thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do you rent or own?

Comment: Adding moisture to returns probably not best idea. Do you have window in bathroom?  Open and/or place fan blowing out.

Comment: venting a toilet into a kitchen seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Aloysius Defenestrate

@AloysiusDefenestrate -Thanks 4UR Reply. I rent, but the landlords solution was/is a no duct/non-vented recirculating fan, meets code-ish,but does basically nothing.

Comment: @crip659 Thx4UR Reply! I agree, normally adding high humidity air into a return prob not great. However, this is why I’m thinking it might work. Its a 6” run (2”x4” + drywall) that would come out into a wide open space thats 15’ form the air handler, which in FL is always on.  
No window in bathroom, that would be too easy. Ext wall is 20’ away& no where to run a duct and cant cut a whole in the bld

Comment: @jasen Thx4UR Reply! I had that same thought while brain storming. LMK ur thoughts, here’s what I’m thinking. Odors could be handled with a filter. However, ur totally right, hot humid air meeting a filter with cooler drier air on the other side would create condensation, which wld=mold and mildew just now inside the duct inside the wall. I’d be making problems instead of solving one.

Comment: Given the renting problem and the 'stinking up the kitchen' problem, I'd suggest you let the landlord put in their crappy fan and let it go. If the humidity really bugs you, maybe get a small dehumidifier unit.